# How to set runtime frequency to 36 hours for Azure Timer Trigger Function App

Tags: timer, cron, azure-functions, timer-trigger

I am trying to run the function app every 36 hours from the last time it was triggered. What Cron setting is required to support this? It looks like we can only set hours from 0-23.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the hours range is between 0 to 23.
If it is 36 hours means, 1 day + remaining hours (n) should be given.

If the CRON expression is written like (`0 24 * * *`), it will not allow:

[image]

You can set the CRON Expression (0 */36 * * *) for every 36 hours in the Azure Functions Timer Trigger.

CRON Expression Editor [Link](https://crontab.guru/#0_*/36_*_*_*)

[image]